# How do I get the Lenovo "Fn Lock" light to work under Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, function-keys

I have a Lenovo E595 running Ubuntu 20.04.  The "Fn Lock" feature on the keyboard works in terms of how it modifies presses of the `F1`-`F12` keys, but the little light on the `Esc` key doesn't show the current state.

To be clear:

- I press `F5` a few times, and the screen brighness is adjusted.
- I press `Fn+Esc`, and "Fn Lock" is now on, but the light hasn't changed.
- I press `F5` again, or several times, and it acts as a normal `F5` (ie my browser might refresh the page).
- I press `Fn+Esc` again, and "Fn Lock" is now off, but again the light hasn't changed.

So, "Fn Lock" works in the sense that it modifies what keypresses do, but the little light on the `Esc` key doesn't come on.  Under Windows the light does toggle, to show the current status.

The behaviour is the same on Xorg and Wayland.

*Does anyone know how to get the "Fn Lock" light to work under Ubuntu?*

Comment: Now reported as a bug in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1881015

Comment: Reported on the Lenovo forums also: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-13-E-and-Edge-series-Laptops/E595-FnLock-light-does-not-work-under-Linux/m-p/5025094

Comment: Kernel bugzilla: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207841

Comment: It's 2023 and I have the same problem on a Lenovo Thinkpad E14 using the latest Kernel 6.2.9 :(

Comment: Solved by updating the BIOS :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the "problem" Pressing Fn+Esc doesn't turn on/off the Fnlock light anymore. I had to go to Lenovo Vantage software: "Input & Accessories" , "Keyboard". then there a could change de light status to on/off...

Answer (score 0):

A code fix has recently been found, but has not yet been upstreamed at the time I write this.  Details are on the kernel bugzilla and ubuntu launchpad reports:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207841
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1881015

Comment: FWIW I see that the Fn+Esc (FnLock) light works now on Ubuntu 20.04, at least on my Thinkpad X1.